# registro não atualiza com EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Estou com um problema meio chato, na tela, eu troco valor do campo, e quando salvo, não gera o erro, e também não salva. O fluxo segue, como se não houvesse nenhum problema esse objeto é assim

```
clientes.endereco
```

implementei o método dessa forma:

```
var db = contexto;
db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

numa tentativa anterior, t.

```
var clienteAtualizar = (from c in db.Clientes.Include(c => c.Endereco)
                                             .Include(c => c.Endereco.Cidade)
                                             .Include(c => c.Endereco.Estado)
                       where c.ClienteId.Equals(obj.ClienteId)
                       select c).FirstOrDefault();

        clienteAtualizar.Celular = obj.Celular;
        clienteAtualizar.ClienteId = obj.ClienteId;
        clienteAtualizar.Cpf = obj.Cpf;
        clienteAtualizar.Email = obj.Email;
        clienteAtualizar.Endereco = obj.Endereco;
        clienteAtualizar.Endereco.EnderecoId = obj.Endereco.EnderecoId;
        clienteAtualizar.Endereco.CidadeId = obj.Endereco.CidadeId;
        clienteAtualizar.Endereco.Cidade = obj.Endereco.Cidade;
        clienteAtualizar.Endereco.Cidade.Estado = obj.Endereco.Cidade.Estado;
        clienteAtualizar.Endereco.Cidade.EstadoId = obj.Endereco.Cidade.EstadoId;
        clienteAtualizar.Endereco.EstadoId = obj.Endereco.EstadoId;
        clienteAtualizar.Endereco.Estado = obj.Endereco.Estado;
        clienteAtualizar.Nome = obj.Nome;
        clienteAtualizar.Rg = obj.Rg;
        clienteAtualizar.TelFixo = obj.TelFixo;

        var entry = db.Entry(clienteAtualizar);

        db.Entry(clienteAtualizar).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

mas ele duplicava o registro nas classes filho.

Alguém tem uma ideia de como resolver isso?

Answer (score 0):

Faltou um `contexto.SaveChanges();` embaixo do `db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;`

Comment: faltou não, é pq estou usando unit of work. Mas mesmo assim, fiz um teste, chamando o savechanges() na classe ele não salva as alterações da entidade endereço, somente da entidade cliente